# Sum value by hourly for IST data in UTC database

Tags: mysql, timezone

My DB in UTC timezone and data inserting in UTC time. I want to sum all values and group by hourly for IST time data. like below,

```
id  data_id value serverTime
1   2       100   2016-05-02 18:30:54
2   2       100   2016-05-02 18:45:54
4   2       200   2016-05-02  19:00:54
5   2       100   2016-05-02 19:15:54
6   2       100   2016-05-02 19:30:54
7   2       100   2016-05-02  19:40:54
```

**Query**

```
select sum(value) as value, serverTime as date
from Data_table 
where data_id=2 
and serverTime between CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 00:00:01','+00:00', '-05:30') 
and CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 10:45:24','+00:00', '-05:30') 
group by year(date),month(date),week(date),day(date),hour(date);
```

above query giving result is :

```
200    
500
```

But Expecting output :

```
600    
100
```

because `IST 12 AM = UTC- 05:30` which means `18:30 to 19:30` but here my query calculating only `18:30 to 19:00`, `19:00 to 20:00`, `20:00 to 21:00` which is not accuracy value.

I want to calculate value for `18:30 to 19:30` and `19:30 to 20:30` for accuracy value for IST time data.

How to solve this?

Comment: You have that backwards.  5:30 IST is 00:00 UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson:  I thought 5:30 IST would be 4:30 UTC (Europe/Dublin). :-)

Comment: @MattJohnson if we are calculating hourly then it should be sum of value from 18:30 to 19:30 in 2016-05-02 because 18:30 to 19:30 is 12:00 AM to 12:59 in 2016-05-03 UTC. This is what i want to calculate.

Comment: @HowardHinnant - LOL.  I just assumed they mean India, not Ireland. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert also date in group by

```
select sum(value) as value , hour(CONVERT_TZ(serverTime, '+00:00', '-05:30')) as hour
from Data_table 
where data_id=2 
and serverTime between CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 00:00:01','+00:00', '-05:30') 
and CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 10:45:24','+00:00', '-05:30') 
group hour(CONVERT_TZ(serverTime, '+00:00', '-05:30'));
```

Test for between condition

```
select CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 00:00:01','+00:00', '-05:30') , 
       CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 10:45:24','+00:00', '-05:30')  from dual;

select CONVERT_TZ('2016-05-03 00:00:01','+00:00', '-05:30') ,  
       CONVERT_TZ('2016-06-03 01:00:24','+00:00', '-05:30')  from dual;
```

Comment: If you use a date group by i think you should use the same time shifting  .. server_time... i have update the answer

Comment: let me check this query and let you know

Comment: Still i am facing accuracy issue. I think CONVERT_TZ(serverTime, '+00:00', '-05:30') is again going -5:30 from fetched data from table(2016-05-02 18:30:54).

Comment: if we are calculating hourly then it should be sum of value from 18:30 to 19:30 in 2016-05-02 because 18:30 to 19:30 is 12:00 AM to 12:59 in 2016-05-03 UTC. This is what i want to calculate.

Comment: I have update the answer please provide the result of this query .. in your question ..

Comment: No still query calculating 18:30 to 18:59 and 19:00 to 19:59 etc..,

Comment: Checking your data and testing seem you have the wrong date in the between condition  i have update the answer with the test i performed ..

Answer (score 1):

By `IST`, I assume you mean India Standard Time, which is 5 hours and 30 minutes *ahead* of UTC.  As a fixed offset, that would be `+05:30`, not `-05:30`.  You're results are incorrect because you have the sign inverted.

The `CONVERT_TZ` function accepts any of:

- `'SYSTEM'` for the local system time zone
- Fixed offsets in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC), which have positive offsets *East* of UTC, such as `'+05:30'` for India, or `'-10:00'` for Hawaii.
- Named time zones, using standard [IANA/Olson TZDB identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), assuming the time zone tables are populated.  India's is `'Asia/Kolkata'`, US Eastern time is `'America/New_York'`, etc.  Using this option requires the mysql time zone tables to be populated, per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).

In general, named time zones are preferred because they accommodate changes in offset due to daylight saving time and historical changes.  However, India has been fixed at +05:30 since 1942 and isn't likely to change in the near future, so it's reasonable to use the fixed offset approach if this is the *only* time zone you need to deal with.

Also note that "IST", like many [time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), is ambiguous.  It can mean India Standard Time (+05:30), Ireland Standard Time (+01:00) or Israel Standard Time (+02:00).  Also note that Ireland Standard Time is actually a *daylight* time zone offset, despite having the name "Standard" in it.  To avoid confusion, please specify your particular location when referring to IST in the future, and don't ever expect a computer to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: "that would be +05:30, not -05:30" how? My DB in UTC timezone which means +05:30 for india and all value storing in UTC time so i should go back -5:30 to get 12 AM value for date 2015-05-03.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to do the math yourself.  `CONVERT_TZ` is designed to do it for you. You specify the `from_tz` and `to_tz` time zones.  UTC is `+00:00`, and India is `+05:30`.  If you wanted to convert the other direction, you swap the parameters, you don't invert the sign.

Comment: If you were to do the math yourself, India is *ahead* of UTC.  You subtract 5.5hr to go from IST to UTC.  You *add* 5.5hr to go from UTC to IST.